# Soft bootloader error on stm32f205rg

Tags: c, stm32, boot

Good day, i have a problem with the loading of 
firmware of the mc stm32f205rg. i used function 
boot_softs to enter to the bootloader , which is 
situated in system memory.

```
void boot_softs() {

volatile uint32_t addr = 0x1FFF0000;
void (*SysMemBootJump)(void);
SysMemBootJump = (void (*)(void)) (*((uint32_t *)(addr + 4)));

HAL_RCC_DeInit();
SysTick->CTRL = 0;
SysTick->LOAD = 0;
SysTick->VAL = 0;
_disable_irq();
SYSCFG->MEMRMP = 0x01;
__set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*)0x20001000);
SysMemBootJump();

}
```

But during the checking with the help of Flash loader 
demonstrator program i have found out that mc dont 
enter in firmware reloading state.

I rechecked  the same function on stm32f207  with no 
changes and stm32f103c8 with address of programm 
beginning  changed.in both cases everything works 
correctly  and mc reloades.

Maybe someone faced  such a problem and can help me 
with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking, Are you saying that your `SysMemBootJump` isn't going to the right place? Or that function isn't being called? That address you're branching to is in RAM, have you put the code there which you need to call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think system memory can be accessed via code, You need to make changes to the external PINs that are responsible for mode selection. M0 and M1.

Upon selecting these pins , you may enter in system mode of your STM32. Here is one link that explains how to send command to bootloader. Click [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/51/5f/03/1e/bd/9b/45/be/CD00264342.pdf/files/CD00264342.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00264342.pdf)!

Comment: Where have you got those revelations from?

Comment: My bad peter, it was boot0 and boot1 pins, using these pins you can move to system bootloader. David explained this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in system bootloader address because it varies depending on MCU.
So check out this documentation from ST: [in system bootloader guide from ST](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf)

As I see you are using wrong RAM address.

Part from bootloader cook book:
[image: took from bootloader cook book]

Moreover, there should be a trigger for entering to system bootloader. As I understand you are using software call method from your main application. This method is not reliable if BOOT pins of MCU are uncontrolled because if serial line or updating software fails you will loose main application and you will be unable to update device. Than you'll need programmer.

So updating, overwriting software which has system bootloader call  is unsafe updating method. I would suggest it only as a own usage update method.

To have safety you should control BOOT pins.
Or implement mini custom bootloader which could be triggered by button (to start main app) and before triggering that mini bootloader  would stay quiet and let system bootloader update main app. Update can't touch mini bootloader memory, this own customized bootloader should be untouched while update. But that is a suggestion.

**Easer way to take control on update is to control BOOT pins.**

For example:
put 3.3V or GND (depends on MCU) on BOOT pins with jumpers , set power and than device automatically will enter to system bootloader.

After update remove jumpers, and after power reset device will enter to your new update application.
That's all.

If you do not have BOOT0, BOOT1 pins control from hardware. I strongly recommending you to check those pins control.
There is a guide from ST about BOOT pins: [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/51/f7/f3/06/cd/b6/46/ec/CD00225773.pdf/files/CD00225773.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00225773.pdf)

Part of description from reference manual:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed answer. but anyway,I've already used this code for stm32f207 and everything worked correctly. stm32f205  has the same address space(you can see it on your screenshot from stm32f2xxx bootloader cook book) but anyway i cant update firmware on   stm32f205 the same way.

Comment: "But during the checking with the help of Flash loader demonstrator program i have found out that mc dont enter in firmware reloading state"


It is always good to recheck. :)

I have a question. And it would be good to concrete problem.:)
Your firmware update fails, or updated firmware does not start after re-flashing?

Comment: Flash loader demonstrator writes "no response from the target" and it means that mc dont enter in boot state and i cant refresh firmware.i thought that i wrote wrong address but stm32f207 works fine. i think that it may be hardware bug, but i am not sure,because usually it is my mistake :)

Comment: Hardware should have boot pins control. If those are not connected to GND or does not have control, than boot pins are floating. And if boot pins are floating MCU start mode is <<<<undefined>>>>.
Also internal system bootloader has timeout. So you should do connection with flash loader <<<immediately>>> after mcu enters to system bootloader. It like 1-2 seconds. So quick hands are needed here. Hope you'll find problem. :)

Comment: @David.O I use in designs my own one. A bit of cryptography, check if the image in the flash is correct etc etc. Not a rocket science

Comment: Thanks for extra advices.